# Recursive Flood Fill - Checking Boundries

Tags: java, recursion, flood-fill

I Have a recursive flood fill of legal neighbours in matrix ( legal neighbour is a neighbour with same color), the flood is not filling all the legal neighbours in the array.
the board I`m using for testing is :

```
int[][] map={{4,0,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0}};

   fill(map,1,1,9,4);// calling to function.
```

the output is :

```
4000
0900
0900
0900
```

**Edit**
If i`m changing the map to:

```
int[][] map={{4,0,0,0},
         {4,4,0,0},
         {0,4,0,0},
         {0,4,0,0}};
```

The output will be:

```
4000
4900
0900
0900
```

The two left 4 number need to be filled too.
and my recursive function is :

```
public static void fill(int[][] map, int row, int col, int color,int oldColor) 

   {

System.out.println("row is: "+row+"col is:"+col);
if ((row <= 0) || (row >= map.length) || (col <= 0) || (col >= map.length) ) return; 

if(map[row][col]==color)
        return;

if(map[row][col]==oldColor)
    {
        map[row][col]=color;
    }
if(col+1<=map.length)
      fill(map, col+1, row,color,oldColor);
 if((col-1)<=0) 
      fill(map,col-1, row,color,oldColor);

  if(row+1<=map.length)
      fill(map, col, row+1,color,oldColor);
  if((row-1)<=0)
      fill(map, col, row-1,color,oldColor);

   }
```

**Changing the code**

```
public static void fill(int[][] map, int row, int col, int color,int oldColor) {
    System.out.println("row is: "+row+"col is:"+col);
if ((row < 0) || (row > map.length) || (col < 0) || (col > map.length) || map[row]                        [col]!=oldColor ) return; 

if(map[row][col]==color)
        return;

if(map[row][col]==oldColor)
    {
        map[row][col]=color;
    }

fill(map, col, row-1,color,oldColor);
fill(map, col+1, row,color,oldColor);
    fill(map, col, row+1,color,oldColor);
    fill(map,col-1, row,color,oldColor);
  }
```

The output is now:

```
9000
9900
0900
0400
```

Comment: That looks correct, what output did you expect? If you expected the 4 at (0,0) to also be filled it will not be since your algorithm only counts cells directly adjacent, not on a diagonal as neighbours.

Comment: Ok, if you can see row-1<=0 if i change it to >= i get stackoverflow.. and this is the right condition for it, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not best answer, but i can't delete my submission.

```
public class Fill
{

    public static void fill(int[][] map, int col, int row, int color,int oldColor) 
    {

        System.out.println("row is: "+row+"col is:"+col);
        if ((row <= 0) || (row >= map.length) || (col <= 0) || (col >= map.length) ) return; 

        if(map[row][col]==color)
            return;

        if(map[row][col]==oldColor)
        {
            map[row][col]=color;
        }

        if(col+1<=map.length) {
            fill(map, col+1, row,color,oldColor);
        }

        if((col-1)<=0) { 
            fill(map,col-1, row,color,oldColor);
        }

        if(row+1<=map.length) {
            fill(map, col, row+1,color,oldColor);
        }

        if((row-1)<=0) {
            fill(map, col, row-1,color,oldColor);
        }

    } 


    public static void main(String pArgs[])
    {
        int[][] map={{4,0,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0},
             {0,4,0,0}};

        printMap(map);
        fill(map,1,1,9,4);// calling to function.
        printMap(map);
    }

    static void printMap(int[][] map)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print("{");
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                System.out.print( map[i][j] + "," );
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes. First of all, your guard excludes row 0 and column 0, so that's one reason why you don't get the result you expect.

Now, fixing that you will get a stack overflow since you will try to fill all neighbours, no matter which color they have. That means that you will visit all cells with color 0 forever. You only want to fill neighbours that have the *oldColor*.

Last, your method expects the arguments *row, column*, but you recursivly call it with *column, row*, so you switch the indexes for each stack level.

Fixing that you can get a simpler method without a guarding *if*. If you expect different length on your rows, then you need to add the guard again.

Showing with a self contained example that prints the maps before and after filling them.

```
public class FloodFill {

  static int[][] map1 ={{4,0,0,0}, {4,4,4,4}, {0,4,0,4}, {0,4,0,0}};
  static int[][] map2 ={{0,4,4,4}, {0,4,0,4}, {0,4,0,4}, {9,9,9,4}};

  public static void fill(int[][] map, int row, int col, int color, int oldColor) {
    if (map[row][col] == oldColor) {
      map[row][col] = color;
      if (col + 1 < map[row].length)
        fill(map, row, col + 1, color, oldColor);           
      if (col > 0)
        fill(map, row, col - 1, color, oldColor);           
      if (row + 1 < map.length)
        fill(map, row + 1, col, color, oldColor);
      if (row > 0)
        fill(map, row - 1, col, color, oldColor);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    floodfill(map1);
    floodfill(map2);
  }

  private static void floodfill(int[][] map) {
    show(map, "Initial");
    fill(map, 1, 1, 9, 4);
    show(map, "Filled");
  }

  private static void show(int[][] map, String label) {
    System.out.println(label);
    for (int[] row : map) {
      for (int val : row) {
        System.out.print(val + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative fill with a guard which then also handles rows with different lengths.

```
public static void fill2(int[][] map, int row, int col, int color, int oldColor) {
  if (row < 0 || row >= map.length || col < 0 || col >= map[row].length) 
    return;
  if (map[row][col] == oldColor) {
    map[row][col] = color;
    fill2(map, row, col + 1, color, oldColor);          
    fill2(map, row, col - 1, color, oldColor);          
    fill2(map, row + 1, col, color, oldColor);
    fill2(map, row - 1, col, color, oldColor);
  }
}
```

Comment: @nullix Added a SSCCE and as far as I can see it works with your input.